# Why can I define something as 'let'?

Tags: javascript, keyword, let

I was experimenting with JS and jokingly tried to redefine `let` keyword and surprisingly it worked.

It does not work with any other keywords like `while`,`const`,`var` etc.
Any reason why JS is working fine with this?

```js
let = 'Weird'
console.log(let)
console.log(typeof let)
console.log(let.length)

let = ['Weird','Very Weird']
console.log(let)
console.log(typeof let)
console.log(let.length)

let = 80
console.log(let)
console.log(typeof let)
console.log(let/80)
```

Also another weird thing:

```js
var let = 'Even More Weird'
console.log(let)
let = 50
console.log(let)
let = (x)=>x**2
console.log(let(3))
```

Comment: This won't work in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Try `(function() { "use strict"; let = 8;})`. In sloppy mode (the non-strict default), that's just a variable assignment to a variable called `let`.

Comment: [`let` is only a "reserved keyword" in strict mode apparently.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can redeclare **let** if you don't specify strict mode by :

```
"use strict"; // firt statement on the script
...
```

it depends also in the engine that execute the code, in **firefox**(spiderMonkey engine) engine you would see an error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let i", but in **V8** in chrome if you don't specify a strict mode, it would work without problem

Comment: Alright I got it, but just for info this code works fine even in Firefox v91.0

Comment: That is not how you activate strict mode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#invoking_strict_mode

Comment: may be i have a different version than you. in my Firefox, it threw out an error.